# How to test Java Predicate from Spring controller?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, predicate

Is there any valid variant to test controller with the `predicate` in it?

```
@RestController
public class QueryLauncherController {
    private QueryLauncherService queryLauncherService;

    @Autowired
    public QueryLauncherController(QueryLauncherService queryLauncherService) {
        this.queryLauncherService = queryLauncherService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/queryLauncher/CMP")
    public List<QueryLauncherDto> getLaunchersCompany(RTAdmin admin) {
        return queryLauncherService.getLaunchersList(admin, QueryLauncher::getIsCompany);
    }
}
```

I've tried to solve this issue using `any(Predicate.class)` but IDE highlights it as Unchecked assignment and it looks pretty dumb. 
The code I've written for the test is:

```
    public void returnCompanyLinks_When_companyRequested() throws Exception {
        when(queryLauncherService.getLaunchersList(eq(user), any(Predicate.class))).thenReturn(queryLauncherDtos);

        mockMvc.perform(get(QUERY_LAUNCHER_URL + CMP).session(mockSession))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(content().json(new Gson().toJson(queryLauncherDtos)));
    }
```

The goal is to run method only in the case when `QueryLauncher::getIsInvestor`.

```
List<QueryLauncherDto> getLaunchersList(RTAdmin admin, Predicate<QueryLauncher> launcherType);
```

Are there any variants to do it?

Comment: Hi Oleksandr!
I'm afraid that the only way to test it if your predicates returns different Objects.

Comment: Show the method signature for `queryLauncherService.getLaunchersList`

Comment: @DwB List<QueryLauncherDto> getLaunchersList(RTAdmin admin, Predicate<QueryLauncher> launcherType);

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
doReturn(queryLauncherDtos).when(queryLauncherService).getLaunchersList(eq(user),
  ArgumentMatchers.<Predicate<QueryLauncher>>anyObject());
```

Some caveats:

1. I prefer the `doReturn(value).when(mock).method` form when specifying mocked functionality,
   but it is easy enough to flip to the `when(mock.method).thenReturn(value)` form.
2. anyObject is deprecated in the latest version of Mockito.
   It is still present,
   but it is deprecated.

**Edit:** I read the 2.23 release Mockito documentation,
and it mentions that `anyObject` is just an alias for the `any` method.

The following should work and is not deprecated:

```
doReturn(queryLauncherDtos).when(queryLauncherService).
  getLaunchersList(eq(user),
  ArgumentMatchers.<Predicate<QueryLauncher>>any());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already found solution with `anyObject()` usage. But the problem is that I cannot use deprecated methods due to project restrictions.